# MySQL group by maximum value in column

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table t with columns aID and ref as follows:

```
aID | ref
-----------
1   | B1.1
1   | B1.2
2   | C1.1
2   | C1.2
3   | D1.1
3   | D1.2
```

Each aID represents an activity ID which is a foreign key to another table. The column ref is a versioning of that activity e.g. B1.1, B1.2

I would like to SELECT * FROM table t GROUP BY t.aID and the result set I am getting is this

```
aID | ref
-----------
1   | B1.1
2   | C1.1
3   | D1.1
```

What I am trying to achieve is this

```
aID | ref
-----------
1   | B1.2
2   | C1.2
3   | D1.2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT aid, MAX(ref) ref FROM my_table GROUP BY aid;
```

This solution is of limited use, and will fail for higher version numbers. Normalise your versioning process.

Comment: this is a good workaround @Strawberry, however, is it better if I have a datetime column and do a MAX(datetime) instead?

Comment: @ExcubeDzynes That's because you have no datetime column.

Comment: I added one though @Strawberry

Comment: so how high are the higher versioning numbers you meant?

Comment: Anything with a component higher than '9' will fail, so 1.10, 11.2, etc. And if we can't see something (i.e. it's missing from the question), then it doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah 10.1 is still working but 11.1 and 12.1 will fail. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If every REF value have the same format (1 letter) use this:

```
SELECT aID,substr(ref from 1 for 1) as ref1,max(cast(substr(ref,2) as decimal(10,2))) AS ref2 FROM `tabla` group by aID
```

You will get a result like:

[image]

Or you can just concatenate both:

```
SELECT aID,concat(substr(ref from 1 for 1),max(cast(substr(ref,2) as decimal(10,2)))) AS ref2 FROM `tabla` group by aID
```

to obtain:

[image]

Comment: what if I also have AAA or AA for example?

Comment: You will have to make a custom function to strip the letters, since regex doesn't work in this context, i would recommend just make another column to separate letters and numbers... Use concatenate if you really need only 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I did it like this

```
SELECT * FROM table t JOIN (SELECT .aID,max(x.ref) as max_ref 
FROM table x  GROUP BY x.`aID`) t2 
ON t.`swp_activityID` = t2.`swp_activityID` AND t.`refNo` = t2.max_ref
```

Managed to solve it after referring to #greatest-n-per-group tag edited by @Bill Karwin